# C# application report with msvcp120_clr0400.dll

Tags: c#

I have an application written in c# VS2013. It has a reports (.rdlc) which suddenly does not work. When the user runs any report an error pops out saying

> vbc.exe - Entry Point not found
>
> The procedure entry point _cntGetFilenInformationByHandleEx could not
>   be located in the dynamic link library
>   c:\windows\system32\msvcp120_clr0400.dll

The rest of the program's functions still work (CRUD) but the reports (all) are not

I would like to know how to properly address this problem, know the cause and prevention

This I've tried:
I've tried fixing the .dll using free software winThruster, Regure - not luck with these.

I've tried overwriting the .dll (Windows 8.1) and copying a .dll that works (windows 10) - no luck

I've tried unregistering and registering the dll - same result

I've tried reinstalling .NET Framework 4.5 but could not since it is already part of the system

I also tried .NET Framework Repair tool - same result

I copied other similar .dll files - no luck

and lastly, I deleted the above .dll file and still get the same error

Thank you for taking time and sharing...

I hope to get information on the cause, fix and prevention.

Thanks,

Comment: Create a new empty project and add a simple report to it (do not copy your existing reports). And see if it works. So we will now if the problem has something to do with your code or not.

Comment: Also, regarding the fact that you deleted the dll and the error is the same. This is probably due to the [file system virtualisation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So, the real dll is under `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120_clr0400.dll`

Comment: Hi Torvin, Thanks. I've downloaded the community version and will work on creating a new project but before going back to code, I will take a look at this system visualization and see what options I get there. Thank you,

Comment: It's virtualisation, not visualisation :) Don't look to deep into it. The only thing you need to know is that if your process is 32-bit, then your dll is in `SysWOW64`, not in `System32`.

Comment: thanks :). on the other thread that Hans pointed me to seems to lead to overwriting .dlls. I will put my updates there. TY Torvin